# The script called "default" which runs "nps webpack" emitted an error

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I am trying to build my project using webpack and I am using the skeleton-esnext-webpack package. Running "npm install" is working fine and the packages are installed without errors, but when I run "npm start" I am getting the following error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXKC9.png

I've tried with different versions of node including: 6.11.0, 7.7.3, 8.11.1, 9.11... With all of them I am getting the same error. I have also installed nps and webpack globally, but that didn't help.
I am working on Windows 8.1 Pro 64bit.

Comment: Maybe nothing to do with the error, but you are very brave working with Windows 8.1 

Comment: Could you post that logfile referred to at the bottom of your cmd output?

Comment: This is the error log: https://pastebin.com/prGkhykH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial error says `Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT` which means the process can't find (or open) `cmd.exe` for one reason or another. This would actually cause a whole host of other problems and it isn't specific to Aurelia or Webpack.

Looking at the NPM log you posted, you don't have `C:\Windows\System32` in your user environment `PATH` variable. It shouldn't be needed there, but with Windows 8.1 you never know. It might just do the trick.

Just in case you don't know how to get there:

- Run `SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe`
- Click `Environment Variables` at the bottom
- In the top list (`User variables`), open `PATH`
- Add `%WINDIR%\System32`

And try again?

Comment: That helped. Thank you very much! :)